# Calculate percentage of ENUM type column with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, percentage

In my SQL database I have one table with some items with a column that are ENUM type and has 3 options: 'pending', 'discount', 'received'

How can I print the population percentage of 'received' option, like (In my table I have 40% of 'received' option that are selected) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the totals for each is pretty simple (assuming your enum column is called 'status' and has a column called id):

```
SELECT status, count(id) FROM myTable GROUP BY status;
```

While it would be possible to write your query to calculate the actual percentages, the simplest thing from there is to do the math yourself

If you choose to use mysqli to run your query, the code would be something like this:

```
// create mysqli connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT status, count(id) AS subtotal FROM myTable GROUP BY status");
$totals = array();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $totals[$row['status']] = $row['subtotal'];
}
```

This will give you an array like `['pending' => 100, 'discount' => 200, 'received' => 50]`):

```
$total = $result['pending'] + $result['discount'] + $result['received'];
$pctPending = ($result['pending']*100)/$total;
```

ans so forth. You will of course have to adjust the code to match how your results come back, but the math applies regardless.

Comment: Actually I don't use while to print the output. I use something like this (I adapted with your code): $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT status, count(id) FROM myTable GROUP BY status;")); Using your example for this query, the output returns "pending"

Comment: Hm. The query will actually return three rows, each row with a status and count. So as you guessed you would have to use a while loop to get all three values. Try the query directly in whatever database tool you use to get a look at the results, and that should guide your coding. However, also note that you should never use `mysql_*` methods. They are deprecated and the latest version of php doesn't even have them at all. The alternatives are mysqli and PDO.

Comment: some (slightly more complicated than necessary) examples of using `mysqli` to execute a statement and loop through the results [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php)

Comment: I went ahead and lifted the relevant part of the linked example (but you should still read up on it) and put it here for completeness.

Comment: Thank you so much Jerry for your help. I solved this problem in this way: $total = $all_pending[0] + $all_discounts[0] + $all_received[0];
$percent = ($all_discounts[0]*100)/$total; where $all_pending, $all_discount and $all_received are 3 separated queries that simply count and sum. :)

Comment: Your solution helps me a lot. Thank you!